# Formal definition and intuitive understanding of homology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology

Homology groups seem to be formally defined as quotient groups $Q$. I feel it is a bit difficult to connect this formal definition with the 'holes' intuition. Perhaps we can find a group $X$ acting on a hole ($S^1$ or the product space of $S^1$'s) so that the hole moves around and covers the manifold, and then find a homomorphism from X to a number set (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}, {0}$), which constitutes part of a homology group.

Questions:

1. If so, why we map the group actions to $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{N}$ (all infinite); actually it seems to me that, for example, for a group $X$ acting on a $S^1$ hole of a torus, $X$ is uncountable, and the quotient group $Q$ should be $\mathbb{R}$.
2. for a group $X$ acting on a $S^1\times S^1$ hole of a torus, $X$ seems to contain only $I$ (identity), then why the quotient group $Q$ is still $\mathbb{Z}$ (infinite) instead of {0} (one element)?

---

It's said that 'The homology groups classify the cycles in a cycle group by putting together
those cycles in the same class that differ by a boundary.' [https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~dey.8/course/CTDA/homology.pdf$\quad$](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Edey.8/course/CTDA/homology.pdf%7Bc9d7dcf4-4def-4d92-93a7-cc5984cc8953%7D)
This explains what the quotient group does. Then I am wondering

1. is cycle group $Z_p(X)$ the same as the module group, or ring, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of integers (both seem to be p-cyclic groups)? $\quad$
2. what is the boundary group. In the link it is said that a) $B_p(X)$ is 'the image of the boundary homomorphism' and b) 'all (p − 1)-chains that can be obtained by applying the boundary operator ∂p on p-chains
   form a subgroup of (p − 1)-chains'. So a) a boundary operator $\partial_p$ (regarded as a homomorphism, a function) maps a $(p+1)$- chain to $p$-chains, and b) all such $p$-chains form a group, which we call a boundary group. But why $\partial_p$ operating on a chain would give a collection of, instead of just one, chain?
3. https://jeremykun.com/2013/04/10/computing-homology/ seems to suggest
   $H_k(X) = \frac{Z_k}{B_k} = \frac{\mathrm{ker}\partial_k}{\mathrm{im}\partial_{k+1}}.$
   Why the $k$-cyclic/boundary group equals the kernal/image of some boundary operator, respectively?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by 'the hole moves around and covers the manifold'?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese like this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleBundle.html. The hole could be a circle, and a fiber of circles covers the torus.

Comment: something useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40149/577710  'the point is that it takes something very hard (topology) and turns it into something easy (abelian groups).'

Comment: this helps: 'the rank of the -th dimensional homology group is the number of -dimensional “holes” the space has. As you stated in your example, for 0, this is counting connected components. Moving to 1, we are counting literal holes.' $\quad$So 1) H0 counts solid pieces (not hole);$\quad$2) what matters is the number of (independent) hole types corresponding (not to the order/size of homology group but) to the rank. So Z*Z ~ 2 hole types, Z ~ 1, {0} ~ zero. It seems not to matter the number n of holes are necessary for covering the manifold. (n=size of the group X acting on the hole.)

Comment: My personal position is that the "holes" thing is completely overblown, and should only serve as a very very basic intuition, not as an actual way to understand homology. It's time to tell the truth: homology is not a thing that "counts holes". (It has the consequence that a lot of students get very attached to this "holes" thing and get confused.)

Comment: @CaptainLama thanks very much. Then how to understand homology group, or calculate the quotient group? Any recommendation of articles, notes, etc.?

Comment: Homology groups can also be understood well for groups. This might be helpful for more intuition. Then there is no "excuse" with holes. Start with some easy examples, e.g., [homology of cyclic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709717/how-to-calculate-the-homology-cohomology-of-a-finite-cyclic-group)

Answer (score 4):

Homology captures the idea of holes in the following way. It's not that the holes move about the space, but that the chains representing those holes are not unique. As a basic example consider the punctured plane $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. The first homology of this space is $\mathbb Z$, but this is represented by any cycle of edges that surrounds the hole. That is why you need a quotient group so that any two cycles with the same winding number end up being homologous.